# Slow, nested For loop

Tags: vba, performance

Code shown is a subroutine that compares the data in two arrays looking for account numbers that appear in one list but not the other.  If it finds one that's missing, it adds the account information to a Sheet.  On a usual day, it finds 10-20 missing accounts out of 2,500 - 4,000 records depending on how far through the month we are.  It's been taking 15-20 minutes for it process the i loop.  Interaction with the Sheet is minimal.  I can't figure out how to improve the code to make it run more quickly.  Suggestions appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To TempCount
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then DoEvents
    FoundMatch = 0
    percent = i / TempCount * 100
    Application.StatusBar = "Checking for missing accounts. Processing row " & i & " of " & TempCount & " - " & percent & "%"
    For y = 1 To OppListRow
        If Saved_User_Input(i, 3) = AccountList(y, 3) Then
            FoundMatch = 1
        End If
    Next
    If FoundMatch = 0 Then
        n = n + 1
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 2) = Saved_User_Input(i, 1)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 3) = Saved_User_Input(i, 2)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 4) = Saved_User_Input(i, 3)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 5) = Saved_User_Input(i, 4)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 6) = Saved_User_Input(i, 5)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 7) = Saved_User_Input(i, 6)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 8) = Saved_User_Input(i, 7)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 9) = Saved_User_Input(i, 8)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 10) = Saved_User_Input(i, 9)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 11) = Saved_User_Input(i, 10)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 12) = Saved_User_Input(i, 11)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 13) = Saved_User_Input(i, 12)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 14) = Saved_User_Input(i, 13)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 15) = Saved_User_Input(i, 14)
        Opportunities.Cells(n, 16) = Saved_User_Input(i, 15)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: you can add `Exit For` after `FoundMatch = 1` and I suppose it's possible to replace the last part with one line, sort of `... .rows(n).columns("2:16") = ... (i)` upd: not sure about the last though

Comment: Would really help to include the rest of your code so we can tell what `Saved_User_Input` actually is....  Could be a Range or an array based on your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace *all* your Opportunities.Cells lines with this *single* one

```
Opportunities.Cells(n, 2).Resize(1, 15).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(Saved_User_Input, i, 0)
```

**Edit** (to eliminate one loop)

Replace the loop below

```
For y = 1 To OppListRow
    If Saved_User_Input(i, 3) = AccountList(y, 3) Then
        FoundMatch = 1
    End If
Next
```

with the lines below

```
On Error Resume Next
foundMatch = WorksheetFunction.Match(Saved_User_Input(i, 3), WorksheetFunction.Index(AccountList, 0, 3), 0)
foundMatch = Abs(CBool(Err.Number = 0))
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Right, `... .Resize` + `Index` 

Comment: You nailed it.  I had to change the (n, 2) to (n, 1) to get the data into the correct columns, but this executes in less than 3 minutes now.  Thanks!!

Comment: 3 minutes to process 4-5k rows is still very slow.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my, "less than 3 minutes" comment.  The part of the code that is shown here now executes in less than 60 seconds.  The stuff that runs before it take s a little time too.  When I ran it this morning, the whole thing executed in probably 90 seconds.  It's a huge improvement and, while there are certainly more efficiencies to be had, it's not worth the effort.  90 seconds is good enough for something run a few times per week.